# Snowflake improve search join IP over Network

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to know the country name of a ip list and the problem is that the time to evaluate the join is really heavy.
This is the idea:

```
WITH IP_GEO_CITY AS
(SELECT
    AS_INTEGER(PARSE_IP(A.NETWORK, 'INET'):ipv4_range_start) AS IP_START,
    AS_INTEGER(PARSE_IP(A.NETWORK, 'INET'):ipv4_range_end) AS IP_END,
    B.COUNTRY_NAME AS COUNTRY_NAME
 FROM
    GEOLITE_CITY_BLOCK_IPV4 AS A
 LEFT JOIN 
    GEOLITE_LOCATIONS AS B
    ON
        A.GEONAME_ID = B.GEONAME_ID
 ORDER BY
    IP_START ASC
)
SELECT 
    UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER,
    COUNTRY_NAME
 FROM 
    UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER AS A
 LEFT JOIN
    IP_GEO_CITY AS B
    ON
        A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER >= B.IP_START AND 
        A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER <= B.IP_END
```

with `LEFT JOIN` I get same result:

```
SELECT 
    A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER,
    C.COUNTRY_NAME AS COUNTRY_NAME
FROM 
    UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER AS A
LEFT JOIN
    GEOLITE_CITY_BLOCK_IPV4 AS B
    ON
        A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER >= AS_INTEGER(PARSE_IP(B.NETWORK, 'INET'):ipv4_range_start) AND 
        A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER <= AS_INTEGER(PARSE_IP(B.NETWORK, 'INET'):ipv4_range_end)
LEFT JOIN 
    GEOLITE_LOCATIONS AS C
    ON
        B.GEONAME_ID = C.GEONAME_ID
```

I think that the problem is `ON` condition:

```
ON
        A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER >= B.IP_START AND 
        A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER <= B.IP_END
```

but I don't know how I can avoid this.

GEOLITE_CITY_BLOCK_IPV4 can contains row like:

```
NETWORK GEONAME_ID  REGISTERED_COUNTRY_GEONAME_ID   REPRESENTED_COUNTRY_GEONAME_ID  IS_ANONYMOUS_PROXY  IS_SATELLITE_PROVIDER   ETL_ID  ETL_TIMESTAMP   FILENAME
1.0.0.0/24  2077456 2077456     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.0.1.0/24  1814991 1814991     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.0.2.0/23  1814991 1814991     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.0.4.0/22  2077456 2077456     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.0.8.0/21  1814991 1814991     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.0.16.0/20 1861060 1861060     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.0.32.0/19 1814991 1814991     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.0.64.0/18 1861060 1861060     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.0.128.0/17    1605651 1605651     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
1.1.0.0/24  1814991 1814991     0   0   2019-10-25 00:00:00.000000000   2019-10-25 08:39:19.000000000   GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20191022/GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv
```

UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER is the conversion of the normal ips to integer.

Comment: What is the performance of the query using an INNER JOIN?  Since your request is for the value of COUNTRY_NAME, you should allow Snowflake to prune better by using an INNER JOIN and only get values that exist back.  That could help.  Without seeing the data, the query profile, the warehouse size. it is very difficult to determine the root cause of the performance.

Comment: What if you flattened the table to be 1 row per IP, so then its an equality join?  Snowflake probably uses delta encoding which works great for sorted consecutive 32-bit integers and probably dictionary compression for the cities, so it might only be a couple of micro-partitions.

Comment: Look at this question, it's VERY similar. The answer there shows how to expand IP blocks into individual IPs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418039/how-can-i-efficiently-transform-a-two-column-range-into-an-expanded-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake tend to not perform well on range scans like the one you have

```
ON
    A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER >= B.IP_START AND 
    A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER <= B.IP_END
```

we have found `between` helps in some cases and your match in a good example where you might be better performance. Which is the pattern used in the [PARSE_IP](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/parse_ip.html) help

```
ON A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER BETWEEN B.IP_START AND B.IP_END
```

we have even found it faster for `>= & <` to use `BETWEEN` and a `<` on the end line:

```
ON A.UNIQUE_IP_NUMBER BETWEEN B.IP_START AND B.IP_END 
   AND B.IP_START < B.IP_END
```

but where we have found SNOWFLAKE to shine is on equi joins, we have found increasing the data 32 times, like as follows, gives massive speed increases, even over 1 billion rows joining to 100 million.

```
WITH ip_geo_city AS (
    SELECT
        PARSE_IP(a.network, 'INET') as ipv4_range_end  
        AS_INTEGER(ip:ipv4_range_end) AS ip_end,
        AS_INTEGER(ip:netmask_prefix_length) AS ip_netlenmask
        BITOR(BITSHIFTLEFT(ip_netlenmask, 32), ip_end) as lookup_key
        b.country_name AS country_name
    FROM geolite_city_block_ipv4 AS a
    LEFT JOIN geolite_locations AS b
        ON a.geoname_id = b.geoname_id
    ORDER BY lookup_key
), ipv4_masks AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TRUE) as rn
        ,32-rn as net_len
        --,BITSHIFTLEFT(1, rn) as b
        --,b-1 as bm
        --,BITNOT(bm, 4294967295) as bn
        --,-b as bnn -- due to two's complement -b = BITNOT(b-1)
        ,BITAND(4294967295, -BITSHIFTLEFT(1, rn)) as net_mask 
    FROM table(generator(rowcount => 31)) ;
), unique_ip_number_lookups AS (
    SELECT a.unique_ip_number
        ,BITOR(BITSHIFTLEFT(m.net_len, 32), BITAND(m.net_mask, a.unique_ip_number) as lookup_key
    FROM unique_ip_number AS a
    JOIN ipv4_masks as m
)
SELECT 
    a.unique_ip_number,
    b.country_name
FROM 
    unique_ip_number_lookups AS a
LEFT JOIN ip_geo_city AS b
    ON a.lookup_key = b.lookup_key
```